# How do you say "imply" in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-choice, new-latin, word-choice, word-order

I need to know how to say the present, past and future tense of "imply" in Latin. I don't know much Latin, I just need the grammatically correct way to say: "Implied ______"

For example, for "Implied Power" Google says "*Sequitur Imperium*."

I don't trust computers.

I would prefer the classical Latin way of saying it,  but it honestly doesn't matter. In fact I don't even need Latin, it's just a habit.

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing I could find to the verb *[to] imply* (at least in the way *implied* is used in this context) in my dictionary was *adfirmō, -āre, -āvī, -ātum*. In this case you'd want to use the passive perfect participle, *adfirmātum* plus the adverb *nōn*. As for the noun *power*, you have a number of options depending on what kind of power you're referring to:

- *potestās, f.*
- *(strength) vīrēs, fpl.*
- *(excessive) potentia, f.*
- *(supreme) imperium nt.*
- *(divine) nūmen, nt.*
- *(legal) auctōritās, f.*

The pairs for each participle-noun pair are as follows:

- *nōn adfirmāta potestās* or *potestās nōn adfirmāta*
- *nōn adfirmātae vīrēs* or *vīrēs nōn adfirmātae*
- *nōn adfirmāta potentia* or *potentia nōn adfirmāta*
- *nōn adfirmātum imperium* or *imperium nōn adfirmātum*
- *nōn adfirmātum nūmen* or *nūmen nōn adfirmātum*
- *nōn adfirmāta auctōritās* or *auctōritās nōn adfirmāta*

When all of these are translated *literally*, they come out to mean something along the lines of *"[type of power] having not been stated"* or *"[type of power] not stated"*, which isn't perfect, but probably as close as you can get to the English idiom *"implied power"* with Latin.

**Minor edit:**

If the phrase “implied power” is being used to describe power of a strictly legal kind, then the word *auctōritās* alone would suffice, since from a pragmatic standpoint, this would would have already meant “implied [legal] power” to a Roman.

Comment: Seconding *auctōritās*

Comment: Would *innuo* be a better choice for *non affirmo*? Why or why not?